# Error is resolving repository

Tags: java, maven

I'm running below command and I'm getting this error.

```
mvn clean install -U
```

It's working correctly on other's machine.I can also access

```
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=300m; suppor
t was removed in 8.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/wildfly/bom/jboss-javaee-7.
0-wildfly/9.0.1.Final/jboss-javaee-7.0-wildfly-9.0.1.Final.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.ideas.MyProj:MyProj:2.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\MyProj\pom.xml)
has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.wildfly.b
om:jboss-javaee-7.0-wildfly:pom:9.0.1.Final from/to central (http://repo.maven.a
pache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused @ line 115
6, column 16: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableMo
delException
```

Comment: Connectivity issue. Can you wget the url to the pom? Are you behind a http proxy? Try to compare ~/.m2/settings.xml, look for proxy tags, on the machines you have.

Comment: U are right Jepper , her symlink is not working, now we have created symlink manually. Let's see afterwords.

Comment: It worked :) after creating symlink , it build went further. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlink was the issue , her setting.xml was not having symlink so we created symlink using cmd and it worked.

```
mklink settings.xml C:\MyProj\install\settings\Env-Local.xml
```

Comment: To be sure, the actual problem you faced was that there was NO settings.xml at all where it should have been. I do not regard your answer as correct.

Comment: No there was a settings.xml present in that location but when I clicked on that file it was not opening correct *local.xml file. So this mklink solved my issue .